# Debug Tomcat Application Startup

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, servlets

Normally, my instance of Tomcat starts-up without any problem. However, when I add a new filter to the 'preview' web app, that application fails to start:

```
09-Jun-2011 12:23:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
09-Jun-2011 12:23:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
09-Jun-2011 12:23:49 com.polopoly.application.StandardApplication destroy
INFO: Application 'preview' destroy started.
```

Tomcat itself starts fine - other wars / web apps deploy and start as normal.

As there's no stack trace in the log, I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. I can't connect a remote debugger to the app because it's not running any more. Can I place breakpoints at the init of the app or filter?

What is the best approach / preferred method for debugging issues during the start-up of a web application in Tomcat?

Comment: there might be some error in `init` of `filter` which hasn't been log

Comment: @Jigar - Yes, that's what I'm thinking, but no error appears in std out. Where should I start to debug from?

Comment: @timbooo - Tomcat 5.5.33 (supporting a legacy environment).

Comment: What IDE and server plugin are you using? In Eclipse Helios SR1 for Java EE developers with the default builtin Tomcat plugin I get those `catalina.out` errors like `SEVERE: Error filterStart` just straight into the Eclipse console. However, I recall that IntelliJ doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm also using Eclipse Helios - but with an external instance of Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help. Thanks to your help, I've found the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294392/java-which-apache-digester-class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure you can. Just put all tomcat source to your IDE and then start tomcat using

catalina jpda start

Put appropriate break points. For example somewhere `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`.

If you still cannot catch the problem use command line:
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y`

`suspend=y` is important here.

But I think that the problem is not in tomcat itself but in your application. So, start from debugging it. Put breakpoints into all entry points (servlets, filters, listeners etc. ) If it does not work, do the following.

Comment out everything from your web.xml. Start app. Working? Fine! Now uncomment half of your stuff. And so on.

I believe you will be able to locate the problem. Good luck.

Comment: If you use the Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin for Eclipse you can debug your tomcat app in Eclipse easily -- set a breakpoint for every uncaught exception and that might reveal the problem.

Comment: Nothing much, except that the string for Java 5 and above can be `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y` instead of `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp...`.