# Java: Which Apache Digester Class?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-commons

I'm supporting a web application / Java servlet that has been failing to start. The issue turns out to be a relatively straight-forward `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception, thrown by `org.apache.webapp.balancer.RulesParser`.

The filter class that throws the exception expects the `Digester` class to exist in the package:

```
org/apache/tomcat/util/digester
```

That package doesn't appear to exist in the application lib, but there is an instance of the class in:

```
org/apache/commons/digester
```

Which *is* part of our current application / project. Both of the classes extend `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` so I'm assuming they are the same class (but probably different dates / versions)?

The RulesParser class exists in the `catalina-balancer.jar` (I don't have the source), so I can't change the package import directly.

What is the later version of the class and which version should I be using (and how)?

Comment: The class you are looking for is in the Tomcat folder. %TOMCAT_HOME%/server/lib/tomcat-util.jar Make sure you haven't overridden the default classpath/loader and forgot to add in the Tomcat directories

Comment: You're quite right. Can you paste your comment as an answer so I can up vote / accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are looking for is in the Tomcat folder. %TOMCAT_HOME%/server/lib/tomcat-util.jar Make sure you haven't overridden the default classpath/loader and forgot to add in the Tomcat directories